# How can the admin add RDS MySQL db instance only reading permission to a user?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Unfortunately I'm not the admin, so I can't see the buttons, links in the AWS of him, but I need to help him doing this, because this needs for me. 
I have a user "A", it can login perfectly into the RDS Mysql db instance through MySQL Workbench. But I also have a user "B", which can't login into the same RDS MySQL db instance through MySQL Workbench (the problem is not with the workbench, it also doesn't work from a c# console app. The security group of the RDS db instance contains the ip I'm trying to login, and as I mentioned, it perfectly works for the other user.

We attached the AmazonRDSFullAccess to the "B" user, but it doesn't have the rds-db JSON line which would provide the reading. 
I don't know which menu points did the admin choose, but after we realized this, he created a policy attached to the RDS service and he clicked to the Read checkbox, which enabled 4-5 policies or permissions (I think this automatically generated the correct policy document), and he attached this policy the "B" user. But it still doesn't work. 
Can somebody provide a step-by-step tutorial with images about what should he do?

P.S.: Sorry, if the question or the description is not well-detailed, but I can't detail that more right now. I will update later based on comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are several levels of permissions here with AWS RDS MySQL database.

1. AWS API
2. Network
3. Database

First, [AWS RDS only provisions the master account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html), from there you can create other users to allow Database level access to the database on the RDS instance.

You mentioned you had network level access by opening the security group of the Database to the IP you logging in from. And the AWS API access by adding the AmazonRDSFullAccess to the IAM user, this would give him access to manipulate the instance itself but NOT login to the database.

I think you'll need to get someone with DBA or the AWS admin privileges to create a user for this person so they can then log into the database.

[MySQL how to add a user](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)